# Linux bash scripting basics condition statements

Tags: linux, bash

What does this statement means? I am pretty new to bash scripting, have searched about various option to check a string not empty like -z, but I had no luck in finding what -x does.

```
EXEC=unknown
if [ -x "$FIND_EXEC" ]; then
  EXEC=$($FIND_EXEC "$@")

fi
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [bash manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Bash-Conditional-Expressions):

> -x file
>
> True if file exists and is executable.

`help test` will also give you similar documentation.

I assume the variable `FIND_EXEC` will have a value something like "/usr/bin/find" (run your script with `bash -x` to find out).

In which case this conditional expression is checking if "/usr/bin/find" exists and is an executable file.  If it is, then it is run with the arguments passed to your script (`"$@"`), and the output of that command assigned to the variable `EXEC`.

Comment: Maybe add that `help test` would also emit help about such options.

Comment: and am I correct in saying that EXEC=$($FIND_EXEC "$@") will give the executable command. I am not sure what $($..) will do?

Comment: `$( cmd )` is a [command substitution](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Command-Substitution).  It runs command `cmd` and makes its output available as a string.  For example you could do `uname_cmd="uname -a"; uname_output=$( $uname_cmd ); echo "$uname_output"`.  You will see that the output of the uname command has been assigned to the uname_output variable.